# How do you get dropdown menus with toolbar.module?

Tags: 7, toolbar

I'm personally more a fan of the admin_menu style dropdown menus than Drupal 7's toolbar. I was watching a screencast by Randy Fay when I noticed he seems to have the toolbar displaying in a dropdown fashion. Does anyone know how he does that?

[Check out the video](http://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-rules-and-stock-demonstrating-power-rules-screencast) at 1:50 to see it in action.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about implementing a feature for which an off-site link is provided to explain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [admin menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module and activate Administration menu Toolbar style , it's a module in the package of admin menu